# Embed a Power BI report in a custom app (with security) without Azure

Tags: azure, web-application, microsoft-powerbi

*Context:*

I'm working on a government dependency. Here they have **Power BI Report Server** locally on their Data Center (*on-premise*). They have several users using viewing Power BI reports (with Power BI licences).

We also have a webapp (made in .NET).

We need to integrate the reports in the webapp. The users login in the webapp and we manage the reports they can see (Power BI Embedded).

All the tutorials are using Azure. We can't use Azure because the organization does not want to.

*Questions:*

1. Why we need Azure to integrate the reports? What does Azure give us that we don't have?
2. How can we integrate the reports in the app (embed) without using Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was recently added to Power BI as a feature: "Secure Embed". From the Power BI web app you can open a report then choose File / Embed to generate a URL or iFrame HTML fragment you can use in your web app.

It's described in more detail in this blog post:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/

... and in this documentation page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-embed-secure

Comment: This works great, and works with Power BI Report Server. The problem is that credentials are prompted to the user. I've been searching but couldn't find a way to do this programmatic (without the user entering the credentials, the app log-in the user). Is there a workaround to this problem with **Power BI Report Server**?